# Jasper Reports Groups and Calculating Percentages of each group of the total

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I have a data series like the following

| Year | Month | Item | SaleCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | Jan | Apple | 2 |
| 2020 | Jan | Banana | 3 |
| 2020 | Feb | Apple | 1 |
| 2020 | Feb | Banana | 3 |
| 2020 | March | Apple | 5 |
| 2020 | March | Banana | 0 |
| 2021 | Jan | Apple | 5 |
| 2021 | Jan | Banana | 3 |
| 2021 | Feb | Apple | 2 |
| 2021 | Feb | Banana | 7 |
| 2021 | March | Apple | 5 |
| 2021 | March | Banana | 2 |

I am grouping data
By Year
then
By Month
then
By Item Type

I would like to to show the percentage sales of each item as a function of the monthly total.  However this is problematic given I use a variable reset on the Month Grouping to count total sales for that month.  Then I tried to use
`F{SalesCount}/v{Total_Monthly_Sales}/100`

as the v{Percent_of_Total}
But as that variable is still being calculated dynamicaly during the internal Item lines basically for the first item its 100 and then each subsequent item is a percentage of the incrementing count..and not valid.  The Total Sales are really on valid when the monthly group has finished being generated. The only solution I can see is use a sql calculation to produce a monthly total field and use this in my percentage variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to use `evaluationTime="Auto"` for a text field that displays the percentage formula based on the current field value and the monthly group total.

Something like this:

```
<variable name="Total_Monthly_Sales" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Month" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{SaleCount}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
...
        <textField evaluationTime="Auto" pattern="#,##0.##">
            <reportElement x="400" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="42be2bf2-495e-4ec9-afbe-6ea99bb6ec34"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SaleCount} * 100f / $V{Total_Monthly_Sales}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Note this will only work if you directly use the field and variable in the text field expression, creating a separate variable for the percentage value will not allow you to use `evaluationTime="Auto"`.